# Видеокарта для Cupy на Python

Tags: python, nvidia

Для операций над массивами (произведение, сумма) использую python библиотеку Cupy на видеокарте nvidia 1080. Для работы с большими массивами не хватает видеопамяти. В диспетчере задач видеокарты кроме видео-памяти никакие ресурсы практически не задействуются (как мне показалось). Как лучше увеличить видеопамять? Использовать дорогую профессиональную видеокарту на 48 Гб RTX A6000 или игровые, например, две по 24 Гб или 6 шт. по 8 Гб? Оправдана ли стоимость профессиональной видеокарты для моего случая?

Comment: Насчёт оправданности моё мнение такое: если эти операции над массивами в конечном счёте принесут Вам денег больше, чем стоят купленные для них видеокарты (какие бы они ни были), то траты оправданы. А если это просто задачка ради "посмотреть, а как оно вообще работает", то конечно же закупать новое оборудование абсолютно точно не стоит того.

Comment: @V-Mor Кажется, это называется "бизнес-план" )  Ну или какая-то его часть